# Mapping SQL table

Tags: sql

SQL Server 2012: 
I have table A (Cust_ID INT , P_ID UNIQUE INT, P_Name, Match_ID, Issue_Date)

```
Cust_ID   P_ID   P_Name  Match_ID  Issue_Date
1         214    J5        1       2009-01-01
1         478    U3        1       2013-05-02 
1         258    21        2       2003-04-05
1         369    65        2       2013-05-02
2         235    69        1       2011-05-09
2         897    36        1       2013-05-02
```

Now basically, rows 2,4 and 6 are populated from row 1, 3 and 5 and hence they have the same Match_Id and 2,4,6 have today’s date. I want to create a mapping table as follows:

I have a table A (CustID, P_ID, P_Name, New_P_ID, New_P_Name)

```
Cust_ID   P_ID   P_Name   New_P_ID   New_P_Name
1         214     J5        478        U3   
1         258     21        369        65   
2         235     69        897        36
```

Please write me a query, I have tried many things but sounds like an easy solution.
Thanks a bunch.

Comment: No. You need to try something and come here with what you get stuck on.

Comment: Please at least show something from those many things that you've tried.

Comment: INSERT INTO #B  (Cust_ID ,   P_ID ,   P_Name )
SELECT cust_ID , P_ID, P_Name from #A WHERE Issue_Date < GETDATE()

UPDATE #B
SET New_P_ID = New_ID
FROM (SELECT P_ID, New_ID =  P_ID from #B ) #A

UPDATE #B
SET New_P_Name = New_name
FROM (SELECT P_ID, New_name = P_Name from #B ) #A

Comment: And obviously its not right. So can you please help me correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   INSERT INTO #B  (Cust_ID ,   P_ID ,   P_Name, Match_ID )
    SELECT cust_ID , P_ID, P_Name, Match_ID from #A WHERE Issue_Date < GETDATE()
    UPDATE #B
    SET New_P_ID = NEW
    FROM ( Select New_P_ID, new = #A.P_Id from #B INNER JOIN #A ON #A.Cust_ID = #B.Cust_ID AND #A.Match_ID = #B.Match_ID AND  #A.P_ID <> #B.P_ID  ) #B

    UPDATE #B
    SET New_P_Name = NEW
    FROM ( Select New_P_Name, new = #A.P_Name from #B INNER JOIN #A ON #A.Cust_ID = #B.Cust_ID AND #A.Match_ID = #B.Match_ID AND  #A.P_ID <> #B.P_ID  ) #B
```